# SQL - Insert into table without repeating the pkey

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert from Table A some specific columns to Table B, in which i make one of them the PKEY:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Vehicle CASCADE;
    CREATE TABLE Vehicle(
        license VARCHAR(20),
        vehicle_type VARCHAR(255),
        make VARCHAR(255),
        model VARCHAR(255),
        year INTEGER,
        color VARCHAR(255),
        state CHAR(2),
        PRIMARY KEY (license)
    );
```

The problem comes when i do the INSERT function, as I use the SELECT DISTINCT option and i guess i just makes the DISTINCT of the columns alltogether:

```
    INSERT INTO Vehicle(license, vehicle_type, make, model, year, color, state)
    SELECT
        DISTINCT(license)
        ,vehicle_type
        ,make
        ,model
        ,year
        ,color
        ,state
    from Importacio;
```

I want to insert every vehicle's info but without duplicates, being its license (plate) what should never repeat in Vehicle. Then this shows when i run it:

> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "vehicle_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (license)=(MD-117254-MB) already exists.
> ```

How can i make an INSERT with taking into account the DISTINCT license only? Maybe i should use the LEFT JOIN but i am not sure about that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function `distinct (a),b,c` is exactly the same things as `distinct a,b,c`

Comment: If you have two rows with the same license which one do you want to pick?

Answer (score 0):

Well since your table importacio has duplicates you must define another filter criteria on what you will exlude.

Eg. You can sort on most recent year.

```
INSERT INTO Vehicle(license, vehicle_type, make, model, year, color, state) 
SELECT DISTINCT license ,vehicle_type ,make ,model ,year ,color ,state 
from Importacio t1
Join (select t2t1.licencse, max(t2t1.year) 'year' from impotacio t2t1 group by t2t1.license) t2 on t1.Licencse=t2.license and t1.year=t2.year
```

Though there may also be duplicates based on year since i dont know your data. You could just add another JOIN-statement to enhance filtering but you should analyze the duplicates and make the join based on that

Comment: 'ERROR:  type "max" does not exist' I am using Postgresql 9.6, could this have something to do with this message? And no, I don't mind the year to be duplicate, as using the license plate we are assuming that the rest of characteristics are the same, and the objective is to have the info of each car in Vehicle

Comment: this is tsql syntax, hopefully you can translate it. max seems to be a valid keyword in postgresql so probably there is some other syntax error. Though obviously they are not duplicates since you're selecting with distinct. Run a query selecting all licenses that occur more than once. select those licences and check if they truly are duplicates.

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function  `distinct (a),b,c` is exactly the same things as `distinct a,b,c`